# Sample size human sciences

Tags: sample, psychology, operations-research

I will apply a questionnaire with 90 questions about the possible requests: very bad, bad, neutral, good and very good, the answers will be categorized into 8 different groups. Subsequently the data will be related to other quantitative tests (audiometry).

So I would like to know how to calculate a sample size that is valid. I have 35 observations, but from the statistical point of view, how can I prove that such sample size is valid. How can I set an acceptable threshold?
When I referred to the conventional way, I calculated the sample size of what I have the size of the population.

Comment: The "conventional way" makes no reference to population size, because it assumes sampling with replacement.

Comment: I really don't follow this question at all -- neither the basis for the statements nor what is being sought. Perhaps you could try to explain in more detail what you need to achieve in plain words (avoiding statistical terms as much as possible). Could you also explain what it is that you see as conventional and why is it a convention (i.e. what the reasoning is for it), preferably with some references?

Comment: Sample sizes cannot be "valid" or "invalid".  You need to do a power analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Most basic statistical concepts, such as estimation and error, let alone specific tools like confidence intervals, aren't considered in qualtiative studies. In fact, I think it would be fair to describe qualtiative methods as an anti-statistical approach to research.